# Prove the existance of a random variable satisfying a given property

Tags: probability-theory

We are given a real-valued rv $X$ with $|X|\leq 1$ a.s. I need to show that there exists a rv $Y$ with values in $\{-1,+1\}$ such that $\mathbb{E} [Y|\sigma(X)] = X.$ I do not know how the conditional expectation based on a sigma algebra plays out. Do you have any suggestion how to proceed or a solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: Suppose that $Y$ satisfies the desired properties. What properties can you deduce that $Y$ must satisfy?

Comment: What do you mean by "plays out"? Do you know the definition of conditional expectation? Have you seen any examples?

Answer (score 2):

It's not always possible to do on the same space. For example, if $\Omega = \{\omega\}$, $X(\omega) = 0$ then clearly we can't define $Y$ on $\Omega$ in the necessary way.

It is possible it we are allowed to extend the space (more formally, there exists some probability space and two random variables $X'$ and $Y$ on it, s.t. $X$ and $X'$ have the same distribution, and $\mathbb E(Y|\sigma(X')) = X'$).

Let $Z$ be uniform on $[-1, 1]$ and independent of $X'$. Let $$Y = \begin{cases} -1&\ Z \geq X'\\ 1& Z < X'\end{cases}$$

Then $\mathbb E(Y|\sigma(X')) = X'$ - it's easy to check for simple $X$, and then taking limit under expectation it generalises to all random variables (probably should be possible to do from some properties of conditional expectation rather than taking definition, but this also works).